# Field Calculator Python code error - "Parameters are not valid"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000989

I am trying to create a new column that combines the values of two other columns for display purposes. Here is the code that I am trying:

"Pre-Logic Script Code" window:

```
def reclass( !Survey1_Interest!, !Survey2_Interest!):
    if(!Survey1_Interest!=="No"):
        return "No"
    else:
        if(!Survey2_Interest!=="NO"):
            return "No"
        else:
            return "Maybe"
```

"New_column_name =" window:

```
reclass(!Survey1_Interest!, !Survey2_Interest!)
```

This produces an "ERROR 000989: Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)" and a "Parameters are not valid" message in the results window.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Tried substituting the parameters "!Survey1_Interest!" and "!Survey2_Interest!" for more generalized ones "col1" and "col2" in the Pre-Logic script window:

```
def reclass( col1, col2):
    if(col1=="No"):
        return "No"
    else:
        if(col2=="NO"):
            return "No"
        else:
            return "Maybe"
```

Kept other window the same:

```
reclass( !Survey1_Interest!, !Survey2_Interest!)
```

This seemed to solve the issue and the column was populated successfully.